# A newbie trying to understand as how this summation was simplified

Tags: algorithms, summation

Can someone tell me as how this summation works? 
I tried simplifying using geometric progression. But I could not

[image: Geometric series?]
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following calculation.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}i2^i & = \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1}2^i\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}1 \\
& = \sum_{0\leq j < i\leq k-1}2^i \\
& = \sum_{j = 0}^{k-1}\sum_{i=j+1}^{k-1}2^i \\
& = \sum_{j = 0}^{k-1}2^{j+1}\sum_{i = 0}^{k-2-j}2^i \\
& = \sum_{j = 0}^{k-1}2^{j+1}(2^{k-j-1}-1) \\
& = \sum_{j = 0}^{k-1}(2^k-2^{j+1}) \\
& = k2^k - \sum_{j = 1}^k 2^j \\
& = (k-1)2^k - \sum_{j = 1}^{k-1} 2^j
\end{align}
$$
The key is to express the factor $i$ as $\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}1.$ Then we get a double sum and can interchange the order of summations. Then we can use genometric progressions.

Comment: just wow. Thanks a lot.